# Mongoose/MongoDb FindOneAndUpdate not working as expected

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update a certain location only if its a status: 0 or status 2. Do not update if status is 1. I only have one copy of that location.

```
Property.findOneAndUpdate({ status: 0, location: req.body.update.location }, req.body.update, err => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
});
Property.findOneAndUpdate({ status: 2, location: req.body.update.location }, req.body.update, err => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
});
```

However, the above code is updating the property even when the status is 1.

```
Property.find({location: req.body.update.location}, (err, Propertyz) => {
    myProperty = Propertyz
    console.log(myProperty[0].status)
    if(myProperty[0].status != 1) { // returns and doesn't update if true
        console.log("updating")
        Property.findOneAndUpdate({ location: req.body.update.location }, req.body.update, err => {
            if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
            return res.json({ success: true });
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("rejecting")
        return res.json({ success: true });
    }
})
```

I changed it to this and it works, but I don't understand why the previous was not working or if there was a way to condense the two previous functions into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update it using one findOneAndUpdate function, add $or operator on your query. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/. This code below search documents that has status 2 or 0.

```
Property.findOneAndUpdate({ $or: [{status: 2}, {status: 0}], location: req.body.update.location }, req.body.update, err => {
if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
return res.json({ success: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
      Property.findOneAndUpdate({ $or: [{ status: 0, status: 2 }] }, { location: req.body.update.location }, err => {
        if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
        return res.json({ success: true });
      });
```

Comment: Some comments to explain your code would really help others understand what you've done. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22558384).

Answer (score 1):

```
Property.findOneAndUpdate({ status: 0, location: req.body.update.location }, { $set:req.body.update} , err => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
});
Property.findOneAndUpdate({ status: 2, location: req.body.update.location }, { $set:req.body.update} , err => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
});
```